IPsec tunnel established, nmap working but unable to ping
I have this Ubuntu VM on my network which is supposed to concentrate traffic towards a VPN and route it through it. Now, what happens is (although nothing has changed in configurations, except for Ubuntu updates which might have screwed some settings):

I cannot ping the addresses on the other side which I'm SURE that should respond
The machines behind the VM can't reach said addresses anymore
Take one of these addresses, that I can't ping, and run nmap towards it - I correctly get the open ports! Not just that, but it's an http server so I can telnet 80 and ask it for some data and it works.
If I run tcpdump when pinging, I obviously see ESP packets going out but not coming back

There's no firewall and this is my nftables:
    #!/usr/sbin/nft -f
    
    flush ruleset
    
    table inet filter {
            chain input {
                    type filter hook input priority 0;
            }
            chain forward {
                    type filter hook forward priority 0;
            }
            chain output {
                    type filter hook output priority 0;
            }
    }
    
    table ip nat {
    
            chain postrouting {
                    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;
                    ip daddr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx snat to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
                    ip daddr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx snat to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
# more destinations here...


            }
    }


Do you see those ESP packets coming out from your VM host system's network interfaces? Are they raw ESP or are they ESP-in-UDP packets? Does tcpdump show anything returning from the remote IPsec gateway, e.g. possibly unsecured ICMP responses?
